# Hold and commit the specific value in the row after specific interval?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am working on hold and commit functionality to achieve hotel booking in the inventory. I have a room table in  SQL Server where I store the number of available rooms for individual room type, so whenever the user books the room I need to hold the specific number of rooms and once the payment is done, I need to commit those rooms what I hold. I am bit confused about how to achieve this? For backend I am using .NET Core and database is SQL Server ?

I created a holdandcommit table as follows:

HoldAndCommit Table

```
RoomId HoldCount CommitCount HoldTime CommitTime
1         2          0       11:00PM    11:00PM
```

Step 1:
Room Table :

```
RoomId PropertyId AvailableRooms
1        1             10
```

Step 2:

HoldAndCommit Table

```
RoomId HoldCount CommitCount HoldTime CommitTime
1         2          0       11:00PM    11:00PM
```

Room Table

```
RoomId PropertyId AvailableRooms
1        1             8
```

Step 3:
HoldAndCommit Table

```
RoomId HoldCount CommitCount HoldTime CommitTime
1         0          2      11:00PM    11:03PM
```

Room Table

```
RoomId PropertyId AvailableRooms
1        1             8
```

Step 4:

HoldAndCommit Table

```
RoomId HoldCount CommitCount HoldTime CommitTime
1         2          0      11:00PM    11:00PM
```

Room Table

```
RoomId PropertyId AvailableRooms
1        1             10
```

1) Initially, the available rooms will be 10 for room number 1

2) Let say, the user wants to book 2 rooms, then I will create an entry in the holdandcommit table with details such as roomid, number of rooms to hold in the holdcount column and hold time as the system time. also, the availablerooms value in the room table will be deducted so that it will become 8 now

3) when the user completes successful payment, I will mark the commit count as 2 and make the hold count as 0.

4) In case of the failure in the payment then holdcount will be 2 and commit count will be 0 and the available rooms should be reverted back to 10. I was thinking to run the background task in the sql server agent, but I am afraid about the performance.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and format those tables as code (select highlight, click {} button above textbox)

Comment: Do you have a reservations table? You can mark the reservation in various statuses e.g. awaiting payment, confirmed, failed payment and count the rooms based on these statuses.

Comment: @SalmanA. Yes I do have reservations table, but once payment is successful, then will make an entry into that reservations table, else will not make an entry into that.

Comment: Then I guess you have to probe both tables to determine the available room count e.g. SELECT 10 - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM confirmed) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM held).

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at your schema designs and it appears like you had a tenancy to engineer it with human readable tables rather than for the process / booking operations.

I'm going to propose for a simple approach and reduce the schema down to an "expiring token repository" -- not exactly sure if there is a better way to describe it, but more on that later...

### Using a `Guid` type

Firstly, I would highly suggest to include a `Guid` type as a primary key as this will allow for an easy WebAPI transition for the future (which will allow for greater compatibility with online booking services).

> Using a `Guid` as a primary key will also provide a layer of overall security (obfuscation) as it will not be a running index value.

For example instead of `RoomId(int)`, we will do `RoomId(guid)`. So now instead of `RoomId=1` we will have something like `RoomId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001` (note this is just an example `Guid` value, a real one will be randomized values.

### Simple expiring token repository

Sorry to use complicated words to describe this solution. If I try and break it down for you, it is basically a very simple table that will keep track of what your inventory (rooms) have "holds".

**Holds Table**

```
Id(Guid)    RoomId(Guid)***   Expiration(DateTime)
a8...e7ef   00...0001         2018-12-31 12:59      // expired
ff...e96a   00...0001         2019-01-08 12:00      // not expired
b0...ff84   00...0001         2019-01-08 12:01      // not expired
```

***Note that I would change the `RoomId` to something generic like `ProductId` or `AssetId` or `ItemId`. As this will allow you to be able to use this repository to put holds on anything you want that has a `Guid` (such as a promotion deal for long stay rooms, or valentines day room, etc).

### Putting it together

The **Holds** table is basically a long ledger or journal entry of every single hold ever taken, no items need to get deleted (or even modified) and can remain on record for any audits or reports you wish to generate about lost opportunities, etc.

How it works...

- Customer makes a hold on a room.
- The system creates a record in the **Holds** table, notes the expiration time.
- Customer continues on to make a reservation.
- The system creates a record in the **Reservations** table.

> When you are searching for room availability you run a simple query
>
> - Check to see how many records `RoomId` has in the **Holds** table that are not yet expired.
> - Then add that amount to the inventory balance from the **Reservations** table.

Comment: My concern here is let's say if the token is going to expire, I want the rooms what I hold to be given back to the repository so that I can make sure the rooms are available to the customer

Comment: This already deals with that concern. No rooms are reserved yet as that is a separate table (as you noted in your original question).

Comment: Could you let me know,  how the expired column will be updated to true ?

Comment: @Harry -- that was just for illustration in the original post (now removed), You just compare the field value against the `DateTime.Now()`. The boolean value doesn't need to be stored in the database.

Comment: I think this will significantly reduce my work .. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Good answer, and similar to one I was going to write, but yours is much better laid out and in more detail than I was planning. Nice one